# Quicksort taking longer on sorted lists

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I ran some tests and found that quicksort actually runs slower the more sorted a list is, which is rather counter-intuitive! I have read the quicksort algorithm on wikipedia but I dont quite understand why it takes longer the more sorted a list is. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Post your code if you want help. I also think that this question is more suited to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: basically on a sorted list, the quicksort will tend in the begining to shuffle the list.

Comment: this specific part of the wikipedia article explain the calculation for the worst case scenario http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Average-case_analysis_using_recurrences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-randomized quicksort will typically choose the first element as a pivot element; when the list is already sorted, this will cause the list to be split into an empty left-hand-side list and a right-hand-side list containing *n-1* elements. The same behaviour will happen in each recursive call, and the total run time will be *n* + *n-1* + *n-2* + ... + *1* = *O(n^2)*.

Comment: if you want to guarantee O(nlogn), use median of medians for pivot selection

Comment: @Daniel - if you want to guarantee O(n log n) it makes a lot more sense to use a mergesort or a heapsort. Median of medians might give you your asymptotic guarantee (I haven't double-checked), but it's complex and the constant factors will be pretty poor.

Comment: @Steve314, I knew there was some overhead, but as I've never used it in actuality, I was unaware how much. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is a well known problem with QuickSort.  One way around the issue is to use an element other than the first one as the pivot element.

This StackExchange entry has really good write up on QuickSort in general: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3/why-is-quicksort-better-than-other-sorting-algorithms-in-practice

This paper goes much more in-depth and takes about the issue for the already sorted list and ways to implement QuickSort that work this kind of anomalies.
http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b93076/p847-sedgewick.pdf